# Problems with compiling a pimpl idiom code

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom

I've been trying to have a go at a 'pimpl' idiom but I just can't get the darned thing to compile.

On Linux Mint with g++ v. 4.6.3 I get the following error:

```
$ g++ main.cc 
/tmp/ccXQ9X9O.o: In function `main':
main.cc:(.text+0xd7): undefined reference to `Person::Person(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is my code:

person.hh

```
#ifndef PERSON_HH
#define PERSON_HH

#include <tr1/memory>
#include <string>

class Person
{
    private:
    class PersonImpl;
    std::tr1::shared_ptr<PersonImpl> pImpl;

    public:
    Person(const std::string& name, int age=0);

    ~Person();

    const std::string& get_name() const;

    int get_age() const;
};

#endif
```

person.cc

```
#include <string>
#include "person.hh"

class Person::PersonImpl
{
    public:
    std::string name;
    int age;

    PersonImpl(const std::string& n, int a) : name(n), age(a) {}
};

Person::Person(const std::string& name, int age) : pImpl(new PersonImpl(name, age)) {}

Person::~Person() {}

const std::string& Person::get_name() const { return pImpl->name; }

int Person::get_age() const { return pImpl->age; }
```

main.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include "person.hh"

int main()
{   
    const std::string name = "foo";
    Person p(name, 50);

    return 0;
}
```

Apart from the code mistakes, could you please advise on the approach I've taken to mimicking a 'pimpl' idiom? Does this conform to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be due to the fact that your `person.cc` file is not being linked in. You may have to adjust your project configuration to fix this.

> Apart from the code mistakes, could you please advise on the approach I've taken to mimicking a 'pimpl' idiom? Does this conform to it?

I would suggest using `unique_ptr` rather than `shared_ptr`, since the `PersonImpl` implementation object is owned exclusively by the `Person` object:

```
class Person
{
private:
    class PersonImpl;
    std::tr1::unique_ptr<PersonImpl> pImpl;
//            ^^^^^^^^^^
    // ...
};
```

Apart from this, you should make use of [constructor initialization lists](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html) to initalize the `pImpl` data member:

```
Person::Person(const std::string& name, int age)
    : pImpl(new PersonImpl(name, age))
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the unique_ptr suggestion and the initialiser list for this particular case, I found a few other problems with my code once I sorted out the linking problem.

Answer (score 3):

You need to build with *both* source files. This can either be done be just putting both source file on the command line:

```
$ g++ -Wall -g main.cc person.cc
```

Or by compiling them one by one to object files, and then linking them together

```
$ g++ -Wall -g main.cc -c
$ g++ -Wall -g person.cc -c
$ g++ main.o person.o
```

The `-c` option tells GCC to create an object file instead of trying to link. `-Wall` enables more warnings, which are always a good idea (they can indicate some unintended behavior), and `-g` tells GCC to generate debug information (good while debugging, especially if a debugger is needed as the debug information includes symbol names).

Answer (score 3):

You're getting a linker error, not a compilation error. When linking, you must list all of your program's source files:

```
g++ main.cc person.cc
```

Or, to compile only, use `-c`:

```
g++ -c main.cc
```

**EDIT**

Additionally, you `Person` constructor is wrong. You're treating `pImpl` as a function, where I assume you want to initalise it. You need to use the mem-initialiser-list syntax for that:

```
Person::Person(const std::string& name, int age)
    : pImpl(new PersonImpl(name, age));
{}
```